# proving a random variable is a martingale

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, martingales

[image]

I am on the final part. I have shown all the properties of martingales, except for the fact that $E|N_n| < \infty$. The solutions state $|N_n|$ is bounded, but I don't see how it is as $S_n$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4S_n-n\leq 4n-n=3n$, and $4S_n-n\geq -4n-n=-5n$. Therefore $|N_n|\leq 5n$, so $\mathbb{E}[|N_n|]\leq 5n<\infty$.

You're right that the sequence of random variables $\{N_n\}$ is not uniformly bounded, but each individual random variable $N_n$ is bounded.

Comment: I don't follow, how does $|N_n| \leq 5n$ mean boundedness, as $n \to \infty$ it's not bounded

Comment: You don't need to take $n\to\infty$ to compute the expectation though. Each $N_n$ is a random variable which is bounded by $5n$.